# Using Str module in OCaml top level?

Tags: module, ocaml

I tried two commands to load Str Module in OCaml top level.
The first command gives me the error "Cannot find file Str.cmo".
I then tried to use the file i was using in top level with the second command. With that command i got "Reference to undefined global Str".

```
#load "Str.cmo";;

#use "my_file.ml";;
```

What do i need to do to successfully load Str module in OCaml top level.

Answer (score 10):

```
# #use "topfind";;
# #require "str";;
```

Answer (score 9):

Modules are "archives", so they are `.cma` files, not `.cmo`:

```
# #load "str.cma";;
# Str.regexp;;
- : string -> Str.regexp = <fun>
```