# Why syntax error in this very simple print command

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml, ocaml-toplevel

I am trying to run following very simple code:

```
open Str
print (Str.first_chars "testing" 0)
```

However, it is giving following error:

```
$ ocaml testing2.ml 
File "testing2.ml", line 2, characters 0-5:
Error: Syntax error
```

There are no further details in the error message.

Same error with `print_endline` also; or even if no print command is there. Hence, the error is in part: `Str.first_chars "testing" 0`

Documentation about above function from [here](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html) is as follows:

> val first_chars : string -> int -> string
>
> first_chars s n returns the first n characters of s. This is the same
>   function as Str.string_before.

Adding `;` or `;;` at end of second statement does not make any difference.

What is the correct syntax for above code.

**Edit:**
With following code as suggested by @EvgeniiLepikhin:

```
open Str
let () =
    print_endline (Str.first_chars "testing" 0)
```

Error is:

```
File "testing2.ml", line 1:
Error: Reference to undefined global `Str'
```

And with this code:

```
open Str;;
print_endline (Str.first_chars "testing" 0)
```

Error is:

```
File "testing2.ml", line 1:
Error: Reference to undefined global `Str'
```

With just `print` command (instead of `print_endline`) in above code, the error is:

```
File "testing2.ml", line 2, characters 0-5:
Error: Unbound value print
```

Note, my Ocaml version is:

```
$ ocaml -version
The OCaml toplevel, version 4.02.3
```

I think `Str` should be built-in, since opam is not finding it:

```
$ opam install Str
[ERROR] No package named Str found.
```

I also tried following code as suggested in comments by @glennsl:

```
#use "topfind"
#require "str"
print (Str.first_chars "testing" 0)
```

But this also give same simple `syntax error`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513046/using-str-module-in-ocaml-top-level. You should also really consider using `utop` instead of the plain ocaml toplevel. It's much nicer to use with autocompletion and history and more. Install with opam.

Comment: there is no `print` command in OCaml, even more, there are no _commands_ in OCaml at all :) It is a functional language, therefore there are only functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An OCaml program is a list of [definitions](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/modules.html#definition), which are evaluated in order. You can define values, modules, classes, exceptions, as well as types, module types, class types. But let's focus on values so far.

In OCaml, there are no statements, commands, or instructions. It is a [functional programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), where everything is an expression, and when an expression is evaluated it produces a value. The value could be bound to a variable so that it could be referenced later.

The [print_endline](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VALprint_endline) function takes a value of type `string`, outputs it to the standard output channel and returns a value of type `unit`. Type `unit` has only one value called unit, which could be constructed using the `()` expression. For example, `print_endline "hello, world"` is an expression that produces this value. We can't just throw an expression in a file and hope that it will be compiled, as an expression is not a definition. The definition syntax is simple,

```
let <pattern> = <expr>
```

where  is either a variable or a data constructor, which will match with the structure of the value that is produced by `<expr>` and possibly bind variable, that are occurring in the pattern, e.g., the following are definitions

```
let x = 7 * 8
let 4 = 2 * 2 
let [x; y; z] = [1; 2; 3]
let (hello, world) = "hello", "world"
let () = print_endline "hello, world"
```

You may notice, that the result of the `print_endline "hello, world"` expression is not bound to any variable, but instead is matched with the `unit` value `()`, which could be seen (and indeed looks like) an empty tuple. You can write also

```
let x = print_endline "hello, world"
```

or even

```
let _ = print_endline "hello, world"
```

But it is always better to be explicit on the left-hand side of a definition in what you're expecting.

So, now the well-formed program of ours should look like this

```
 open Str

 let () = 
    print_endline (Str.first_chars "testing" 0)
```

We will use `ocamlbuild` to compile and run our program. The `str` module is not a part of the standard library so we have to tell `ocamlbuild` that we're going to use it. We need to create a new folder and put our program into a file named `example.ml`, then we can compile it using the following command

```
 ocamlbuild -pkg str example.native --
```

The `ocamlbuild` tool will infer from the suffix `native` what is your goal (in this case it is to build a native code application). The `--` means run the built application as soon as it is compiled. The above program will print nothing, of course, here is an example of a program that will print some greeting message, before printing the first zero characters of the `testing` string,

```
open Str

let () =
  print_endline "The first 0 chars of 'testing' are:";
  print_endline (Str.first_chars "testing" 0)
```

and here is how it works

```
$ ocamlbuild -package str example.native --
Finished, 4 targets (4 cached) in 00:00:00.
The first 0 chars of 'testing' are:
```

Also, instead of compiling your program and running the resulting application, you can interpret your the `example.ml` file directly, using the `ocaml` toplevel tool, which provides an interactive interpreter. You still need to load the `str` library into the toplevel, as it is not a part of the standard library which is pre-linked in it, here is the correct invocation

```
ocaml str.cma example.ml
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. I want to run the script with command `ocaml` and not build with `ocamlbuild`. Is that possible?

Comment: yep, such a simple script could be run using the `ocaml` command (which is the ocaml repl), here is how to invoke your script `ocaml str.cma example.ml`
See `man ocaml` for more options.

Comment: Yes `ocaml str.cma example.ml` finally works. It will be great if you can add this to your answer and give a brief explanation about it.

Answer (score 2):

You should add ;; after "open Str":

```
open Str;;
print (Str.first_chars "testing" 0)
```

Another option is to declare code block:

```
open Str
let () =
    print (Str.first_chars "testing" 0)
```

Comment: 1) there is no such thing as "code block" in OCaml.
2) it is, in general, a bad idea to use `;;` in `.ml` files, this symbol should be reserved for toplevel interactions.